# Apply logical and/or operations along an axis in numpy python

Tags: python, numpy, simplify

I have a numpy array of shape `(h, w, c)`. I want to apply logical and/or operations along the channels. Is there a simpler way to do it than the below example? I tried using [apply_over_axis()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html) function, but I couldn't get it to work

Ex: For simplicity, I'll consider a 2D array.

```
import numpy

>>> a = numpy.arange(6).reshape(2,3) % 2 == 1
>>> a
array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True]])
```

I want to apply `and` operation along `axis=1` to get the result as

```
array([False, False])
```

I can get it as follows:

```
>>> a[:, 0] & a[:, 1] & a[:, 2]
```

But, is there a simpler way to do it? I tried using [apply_over_axis()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html) function as follows

```
>>> numpy.apply_along_axis(numpy.logical_and, a, [1])
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in apply_along_axis
  File "/home/nagabhushan/anaconda3/envs/11_VPTU_GPU/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 361, in apply_along_axis
    axis = normalize_axis_index(axis, nd)
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: So you want all on axis 1: `a.all(axis=1)`?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Actually this question has been asked before hence I have closed it. However I am glad that I could help :)